# How can Microsoft Video Indexer API process live streamed video?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

How can we use Microsoft Video Indexer API to process live streamed video.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to have a delay (let's say 10 seconds) between the time the video is being recorded and the time the video is actually being streamed to the user with the outputs of the **Video Indexer API** to allow time for processing.

What you'll have to interpret in order to achieve your goal is download the last (let's say 10 seconds) chunk of your live streaming video to your server, use the **Video Indexer API** to process it, and then return the results along with the 10 seconds that was just processed, and repeat while considering the exact time it will take to complete that process.